# mysql views codeigniter active record

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-2

my question is, is there anything different about writing models that will consume mysql views using active record? I would like to make some mysql views and have some models to consume the data contained in the views at any given time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. Views are only a set of preselected rows from one or more tables so there should be no problem to access them thru a model.